# Set a value in a property - Setter never reached

Tags: c#, properties, binding, getter-setter, setter

I am trying to enable the use of a button based on the value of a property: EnableAireDePrefabrication.
This property takes the value true depending on certain conditions described below.

```
public class ChantierViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private bool _enableAireDePrefabrication;
public bool EnableAireDePrefabrication
{
    get { return _enableAireDePrefabrication; }
    set
    {
        if (Etude.Mf_Balcons == "Fabrication sur chantier" || Etude.Mf_PlancherPredalles == "Fabrication sur chantier" || Etude.Mf_Poteaux == "Fabrication sur chantier" || Etude.Mf_Poutres == "Fabrication sur chantier")
        {
             _enableAireDePrefabrication = true;
        }
        else
        {
             _enableAireDePrefabrication = false;
        }
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Next, you should know that the Mf_xxx properties of the Study class can take the values "Fabriqué sur chantier" and "Fabriqué à l'usine".

The aim would be that when the user selects "Fabrication dur chantier", the "Aire de préfabrication" button becomes accessible (see images).

Namely that the binding of all my properties works, but it is the setter that seems never to be reached in my property EnableAideDePrefabrication.

Thank you for your help!
Hugo

[Button disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMv2j.png)

[Proof nb.1 that the button should be enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW08V.png)

[Proof nb.2 that the button should be enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edUY6.png)

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding what a property setter is for. When you call `myModelInstance.EnableAireDePrefabrication = true;` or `myModelInstance.EnableAireDePrefabrication = false;`, the setter will be trigged with the corresponding value (the right-side of the =) made available via `value`. You're not assigning a value to this property anywhere, so the setter isn't ever being called.

Comment: [Hopefully this demo will illustrate that](https://rextester.com/FDWV57626)

Comment: I know that I made a hugo mistake and now I have changed that :

`if(...)
{
_enableAireDePrefabrication=value;
}
else { _enableAireDePrefabrication = value;}`

Now, the problem is that my conditions are useless, and I don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: I mean, if you understand what I am trying to do, tell me if it is possible or not ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have a solution for you. I'm a backend developer (making Web APIs with ASP.NET) and while I know how properties work because it's a fundamental part of C#, I don't know how to make the kind of condition you want with UI binding, etc. because I've not done anything with that and it's not my area of expertise.